# How can I find out which package is triggering the installation of i386 libraries when using Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: software-center, dpkg, synaptic

I'm running Precise 64bit. One of the packages I've installed recently needed 32bit packages which triggered the installation of a whole bunch of i386 dependencies. How can I look up which package that is?

Update: How can I identify and remove all packages which are not 64bit?

Comment: Do you need the name of recently installed package which triggered the library installation? in that case, you can see them in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: I'm actually not interested in one particular package. I thought there must be a general solution to search with dpkg for all non-64bit packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would try to identify which package triggered installation of 32 bit packages:

- start synaptic
- find a 32-bit package which has been installed as a dependency (`libc6-i386` is a good candidate)
- try to uninstall it. If another package depends on it (which should be the case because that's why the library has been installed in the first place), Synaptic will tell you that you need to uninstall that another package as well.
- once you uninstalled the package which triggered installation of the 32-bit libs, you can run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove packages which were installed as dependencies of uninstalled packages.

Similarly, to find all packages which depend on 32-bit libs, try to uninstall, say, `libc6-i386` - this should trigger un-installation of all 32-bit packages in the system.

I'm sure there's also a magic command line one-liner involving dpkg, awk and grep which does the same :)