# Accidental Install of i386

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (64 Bit) and and while trying to fix a different problem, I of course created a new one.  I accidentally installed a package called:

`vpnautoconnect_2.1.0ubuntu5_i386.deb`

from [this archive](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vpnautoconnect/files/)

using gdebi.

Now, my machine is behaving funny even though I already removed the package... no doubts remnants of the i386 architecture packages at play.

Anyone know how to safely remove the unwanted packages that are causing me headaches... (that type of night ;-(  )

Thanx

Comment: prior to the accidental installation shutter worked fine... now it won't launch...  gdebi that I used to install the bad package was somehow auto removed itself.. at one point all of my panel indciators vanished and I only got them back by reseting unity

Answer (score 0):

So things are swinging back in my favor.  [Thanks to askubuntu,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182030/how-can-i-find-out-which-package-is-triggering-the-installation-of-i386-librarie) I was able to identify the i386 library that all apps on a 64 bit machine use to run 32 bit aps like wine.   It's called 'libc6-i386'.

I then ran `sudo apt-get remove --purge libc6-i386*`

`reboot`

The I reinstalled the reinstalled package, so that programs like wine can have access to it as necessary.  `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`

Now my machine is humming along as normal...  We learn by trial and error...

D